# When mashiach will come will Batei midrashim be transplanted to Israel?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, synagogue, messiah, travel, home-house

I believe I heard that when Mashiach comes the batei midrashim (houses of study), batei knessiot (synagogues) and even houses of Jews outside Israel will fly or be transplanted to Israel.

Has anyone heard the same or has a source?

Comment: This Midrash is from Bavli [Megillah 29a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=29&format=pdf)

Comment: Double AA, that sounds like an answer.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot It was just before Shabbat and I didn't have time to track down the dupe then.

Comment: @DoubleAA, This is not a duplicate question. The original was only addressing the subject of the Shuls and Yeshivas. See this link: judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28477/… But this question is mistakenly including the homes of Jews living outside Israel together with the Shuls and Yeshivot. There is a source for this idea relating to the 'rechush gadol' that Bnai Yisroel took out of Mitzrayim, but it doesn't relate to the idea behind the Shuls and Yeshivot returning to Israel. If you reopen the question, I can provide details.